# How to Create Dynamic Variable Names in a For Loop in R

Tags: r, loops, syntax

I have a dataset/table (called **behavioural**) with data from **24** participants - these are named in the format: 's1' to  's24'.

The first 6 rows in the table/dataset:

```
head(behavioural)[c(1,17)]
   subj     recognition_order
1   s1                 2
2   s1                 6
3   s1                 7
4   s1                 8
5   s1                 9
6   s1                10
```

I want to create a subset for **each** participant and order each of these subsets by the variable `recognition_order`

I have created a loop to do this:

```
behavioural <- read.table("*my file path*\behavioral.txt", header = TRUE)

subj_counter <- 1


for(i in 1:24) {
subject <- paste("s", subj_counter, sep = "")
subset_name <- paste(subject, "_subset", sep="")

[subset_name] <- behavioural[which(behavioural$subj  == subject), ]
[subset_name] <- subset_name[order(subset_name$recognition_order),]

subj_counter = subj_counter + 1

print(subset_name)
print(subj_counter)
}
```

And I'm pretty sure the logic is solid, except when I run the loop, it does **not** create 24 subsets. It just creates 1 - `s24_subset`.

**What do I need to do to the bit before "<-" in these 2 lines of code?**

```
[subset_name] <- behavioural[which(behavioural$subj  == subject), ]
[subset_name] <- subset_name[order(subset_name$recognition_order),]
```

Because `[subset_name]` isn't working.

I want the `[subset_name]` to be dynamic - i.e. each time the loop runs, its value changes and it creates a new subset/variable each time.

I have seen things online about the `assign()` function but I'm not quite sure how to implement this into my loop?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't do this. Collect all your similar results into a named list. Something more like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames. It will be so much easier for you to work with in the long run.

Comment: Also, when asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Make sure all variables are defined.

Comment: I would suggest using the `split` function to split your original dataset into a list with the 24 subset.  It is much easier to would with a list (using lapply) then the 24 separate dataframes.

Comment: Mr Flick - the entire code I posted above could be run straight away on someone else's computer, provided they have the 'behavioural.txt' file, but how do I put/attach the text file to this question?

Comment: @Dave2e - do you mean something like this? `my_split_list <- split(behavioural, behavioural$subj)`'This creates a very large list, but how do I then sort this by 'recognition_order' per subject?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to order the items inside the results of a `split` than just use `lapply` to pass the needed function calls to do the ordering on a single dataframe at a time (which are re-bundled together by `lapply` after the ordering:

```
my_split_list <- split(behavioural, behavioural$subj)
ord.list <- lapply( my_split_list, function(d){ 
                   d[ order(d[['recognition_order']]) , ] }
```

This is a common paradigm called "split-apply-combine": "The Split-Apply-Combine Strategy for Data Analysis" https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v040i01/v40i01.pdf

Answer (score 3):

```
for(i in 1:5) {
  assign(paste0("test_",i),i) 
}
test_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "test_"))`
```

I hope you get a good answer. There is a good way to create an assign function and to bind this pattern in mget. I've outlined a lot of questions for R and Python about dynamically generating variables. Attached to the following link.
- [Creating Variables Dynamically (R, Python)](https://medium.com/@unfinishedgod/creating-variables-dynamically-r-python-5ea91a56f59e)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with `eval()` and `parse()`, like so:

```
eval(parse(text = paste(subset_name, "<- subset_name[order(subset_name$recognition_order),]", sep = '')))
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I tried this code and it did not work.